# How can i burn fat without losing weight?

Tags: workout, jogging, bellyfat, burn-fat

I am 21 years old 1.75m and like 64.5kg. and started doing kickboxing 3 days a week for 4 months now. Kickboxing contains endurance and strength training nearly for the whole body. I didn't do anything for a long time before that, except for playing football(soccer) for a half year (during the 4 years where I didn't do anything except that...) Since I started kickboxing I noticed a big change in my body. My shoulders are getting wider and my arms don't look that weak anymore.

But I still have one Problem. I have a fat around my belly it isn't extremely much. But it sucks. I want to get an ABS until August, so I can show off my body without getting uncertain and losing confidence about my body.

One and a half weeks ago, I started doing situps daily. 40 Situps, then 20 pushups and after that 40 situps again. But is this really usefull for burning fat there? Or what can I do for burning fat? I thought of going jogging on the days I dont do kickboxing, but I don't want to lose weight, just burn fat. How can I achieve that?

EDIT: I don't know if it's important but the workout schedule looks like this:

Monday: Kickboxing

Tuesday: Situps-Pushups (I want to add jogging)

Wendsday: Kickboxing

Thursday: Situps-Pushups (I want to add jogging)

Friday: Kickboxing

Saturday: Situp-Pushups (not every saturday, only when i am motivated :P )

Sunday same as Saturday except I want to add jogging.

Comment: You seem to subscribe to the myth of spot reduction. Please see [my answer here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/3933/1771), or [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/6249/1771). For solutions, see the answers to [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/4640/1771).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lose fat and gain muscle at the same time, but you cannot do so optimally. People who first start a diet and workout programs are typical examples of this.

If your focus is on a lean midsection, you need to get your diet sorted out. You can workout until you are blue in the face and still not achieve this goal. I suggest you take a look at the diet recommendations of [Nate Miyaki](https://www.google.com/search?q=Nate%20Miyaki). He is active on the web and wrote  the Samurai Diet (Amazon). You might also see these threads on Fitness SE

[How can I get a flat stomach?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-can-i-get-a-flat-stomach)

[What is the most effective plan to get abs?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/5670/what-is-the-most-effective-plan-to-get-abs)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think diet is the key since you're already active.  I found that tracking my calorie intake helped as it enabled me to know when I should eat more or less food during the day.

Comment: Care to elaborate on why you think it helped?