# How to maximize benefits when doing regular fasting?

Tags: exercise, weight-loss, diet

Because of religious stuff I'll be fasting from around 5 AM to 8 PM meaning 15 hour a day for a whole month, I was thinking I should use this to lose some weight (85 kg, 177 cm) and specially belly fat but I'm not sure how to proceed, to be honest I don't want to hurt my health specially because during this 15 hour fasting I can't even drink a single drop of water.
So with the described time frame, when do you think is the best time to exercise ? and is it a good idea to hold back in eating too much within the remaining 9 hour or should I try to eat as much as I can ?.
I really like to use this time as best I can to increase my physical fitness so any advice and tips is much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

On a quick note, [it is impossible to target fat loss](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/when-fat-is-burnt-where-is-it-taken-from/6251#6251) on your belly. You will lose fat everywhere on your body when you do lose fat, and as a male you will likely see fat on your belly stay longer than other places.

> What is the best time to work out during a fast?

Considering Ramadan starts tonight, I'm going to assume this is the fast you are talking about. I am not sure what your day to day looks like, or much about Ramadan. A quick google search brought up [this site](https://ramadanreset.com/exercise/best-time-to-workout-in-ramadan/) explaining pros and cons for this culture and when to workout.

I can however speak for the health benefits of their top two options, and agree with both. These are both non-fasted options. Considering you can't drink water during the fast, I would definitely stay away from working out during your fast. Plus working out while having some food in your system feels much better. The research is conflicting on fasted cardio anyways. ([meta-analysis](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27609363/) showing higher VO2 during workout in fasted group) ([study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/25429252/) showing no difference) ([study](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21411835/) showing higher VO2 in the FED group 24 hours after exercise)

[image]
[image]

> Is it a good idea to hold back in eating too much within the remaining 9 hours or should I try to eat as much as I can?

Your goal is to lose weight. You will lose weight if you consume fewer calories than you use. For a much more detailed answer on how to lose weight, see [this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/how-to-lose-fat-fast-and-healthily/13256#13256). As for how much you personally should consume, if you want to lose weight, make sure you eat less when you break your fast than currently eat in a day. If you want to keep it off after the fast, you must continue eating the same amount of calories, or you will put it back on, and potentially even more.